# ViewPager blocks Fragment's View's OnClickListeners

Tags: android, android-viewpager, onclicklistener

I currently have a view pager in a tab layout

```
//Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new SettingsFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    //Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

And then the fragments in the view pager have TextViews with OnClickListeners attached

```
final TextView zSemTxt = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.zSemTxt);
        zSemTxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mSelectedTextView = zSemTxt;
                showDialogToSelectClass();
            }
        });
```

My issue is the OnClickListeners are never called, it appears that all touches go to the ViewPager and never goes through to the TextViews. I've tried things like viewPager.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true); but none of it change anything.
Ideas?

Comment: Although, I haven't worked with `ViewPager` much but, have you tried setting `android:clickable="false"` on your `R.id.viewpager`?

Comment: can u tel me y r u checking whether a textview is null?

Comment: The null check is just to a habit I got from suppressing a warning Android Studio gives in some activities saying that the view may be null

Answer (score 0):

Show more code.

Probably onClick dosen't work because your textview = null.

```
final TextView zSemTxt = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.zSemTxt);
```

Are You sure about this?

I dont see your code but try

```
final TextView zSemTxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.zSemTxt);
```

where **view** is your fragment inflated view.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out neither the onActivityCreated or onCreateView were being called on the fragment.
The solution was to go to the PageFragment class I was using to manage which fragment was displayed by the ViewPager and add the onClickListeners to there. The fragments were being inflated there which is why the other classes were never called.